# Submitting date from form via ExtJS.request.Ajax POST to Flask API

Tags: ajax, datetime, extjs, flask, flask-wtforms

Why are dates such a royal PITA:

I have an ExtJS (ver. 6.2.0) form panel with a date picker:

```
{
    allowBlank:false,
    fieldLabel: 'Consent Date',
    name: 'consent_date',
    emptyText: 'consent_date',
    //inputType: 'date',
    xtype: 'datefield',
    //maxValue: new Date(),
    format: 'm/d/Y',
    submitFormat: 'm/d/Y'
}
```

And I am submitting this in my controller via an Ext.request.Ajax call:

```
onNewPatientFormSubmit: function () {
    var formPanel = this.lookupReference('newPatientForm'),
        form = formPanel.getForm(),
        url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/mrnconsentview/api/create';

        if (form.isValid()) {
            values = form.getFieldValues(true);

            console.log('form');
            console.log(form);
            console.log(values);

            form.reset();
            Ext.MessageBox.alert(
                'Thank you!',
                'Your inquiry has been sent. We will respond as soon as possible.'
            );

            Ext.Ajax.request({
                method: 'POST',
                cors: true,
                timeout: 6000000, //default is 30 seconds
                useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
                url: url,
                params: values,
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                },
                disableCaching: false,

                success: function (response) {
                    json = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                    console.log('json');
                    console.log(json);
                    console.log(response);

                    if (response.status === 200) {
                        console.log(json.items);

                    }
                    else {
                        Ext.MessageBox.alert('Error', response.message);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
}
```

The problem is, regardless of the submitFormat in my form panel, it ALWAYS renders submitted consent_date formatted like: `Fri Jan 02 1995 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST)` and thus, the JSON in my Ajax form submission looks like:
`{mrn: "testing12345", consent_date: Mon Jan 02 1995 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST)}`

It's even worse on the server (Flask, with wtforms), where it looks like: `1995-01-02T00:00:00` and thus, chokes since it does not see it as a datetime object... The response from the server is

```
{
  "error_details": {
    "consent_date": [
      "Not a valid datetime value"
    ]
  }, 
  "message": "Validation error"
}
```

I could do post processing on it, but I would prefer to get it without having to do so. (I tried minimal post processing using the python datetime method, but gave up... ala: `t = datetime.datetime.strptime(dict(request.form)['consent_date'][0], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")` and got an error: `time data '1995-01-02T00:00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S.%f'`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [getValues](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.Basic.html#method-getValues) form method instead. `getFieldValues` doesn't take into the account the `submitFormat`.

> *getFieldValues*: ..This is similar to getValues except that this method
>   collects **type-specific data values** (e.g. Date objects for date fields)
>   while getValues returns only String values for submission.
>
> *getValues*: ..This is similar to getFieldValues except that this method collects only **String values for submission**, while
>   getFieldValues collects type-specific data values (e.g. Date objects
>   for date fields.)

Comment: Please keep in mind that not only dates, but also checkboxes behave differently between getFieldValues and getValues. Depending on the data format expected, you may have to write your own aggregation function that uses `getFieldValues` of checkbox fields and `getValues` of date/time fields. (My backend can easily work with arrays of values, but not with arbitrarily formatted dates...)

Comment: Perfect (NB: I had tried `getValues` earlier, but for some stupid reason thought that I had to POST JSON, and thus went to `getFieldValues` instead)!